# Prove that $\lambda(A + B) \ge \lambda(A) + \lambda(B) $ for A and B being half-open intervals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

> Prove that for the Lebesgue-measure $\lambda$, the inequality
>
> $\lambda(A + B) \ge \lambda(A) + \lambda(B) $
>
> holds.

So, this task is divided in some smaller tasks, and I'm supposed to begin with the following one:

> Show that the inequality holds for half-open intervals
>
> $A = [a_1, b_1)$ and $B = [a_2, b_2)$
>
> with $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \Bbb R$, $b_1 > a_1$ and $b_2 > a_2$.

I tried to do a case analysis, taking a look at $A \subset B$, $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. Yet, I only came to the conclusion that, no matter what case I try to prove, that there is always only the equality between $A$ and $B$.

So, we know that $A + B = [a_1, b_1) + [a_2, b_2) = [a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2)$. This leads to

$\lambda(A + B) = \lambda([a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2)) = (b_1 + b_2) - (a_2 + a_1) = b_1 + b_2 - a_2 - a_1 = b_1 - a_1 + b_2 - a_2 = \lambda([a_1, b_1)) + \lambda([a_2, b_2)) = \lambda(A) + \lambda(B).$

Of course this doesn't contradict the statement above, but I guess there is more to show here. We are allowed to use the usual properties of a measure.

**Edit:**

So, basically, I couldn't find an example where the equality didn't hold. I guess this is exactly sub-task wats me to find? We later work with $A$ and $B $ being compact, so I might get a different result, but I'm not sure.

**EditEdit:**

It turned out that my solution is perfectly fine, I simply refused to believe that the equation would hold for every interval - but it does.

Comment: If you want to do the case analysis, note that for $A \cap B = \emptyset$ i.e disjoint, then you can use countable additivity to show $\lambda(A \cup B) = \lambda(A) + \lambda(B)$. If $A \subseteq B$, then $B = A \cup (B \cap A^{c})$ is a disjoint union and using countable additivity again you get $\lambda (B) = \lambda (A) + \lambda(B \cap A^{c}) \ge \lambda(A)$ as measures are non-negative.

Comment: But what does $\lambda(B) \ge \lambda(A)$ give me then?

Comment: Nothing, I misread the question. It's too late at night for me sorry.

Comment: Do you have the measure of the union of disjoints is the sum of the measures?

Comment: Haha, no problem. Yes, we know all that stuff about the properties of measures.

Answer (score 2):

For the strick inequality you may take $A=B=C$ where C is the standard Cantor set. We know $C+C=[0,2]$ and $\lambda(C)=0$ so here $$\lambda(C+C) > \lambda(C)+\lambda(C)$$
Or, Just take $A=(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ and $B=(1,2)$ then $A+B=(1,5)$ here $\lambda(A+B)=4$ but $\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $A\cap B=\emptyset $. Then since $A,B$ are compact so $d(A,B)=\inf \{|a-b|:a\in A,b\in B\}>0$ say $d(A,B)=r>0$

Let $\epsilon >0$ .Then $\exists $ sequence $\{I_n\}$ disjoint open intervals each with diameter $<r$ such that $A+B\subseteq \cup I_n$ and $\lambda(A+B)+\epsilon>\sum l(I_n)$

Now $A\subseteq A+B;B\subseteq A+B\implies A\subseteq \cup I_n,B\subseteq \cup I_n$.

Let $\{I_n\}^{'}$ denote those intervals which contain only points of $A$,and Let $\{I_n\}^{''}$ denote those intervals which contain only points of $B$.

$A\subseteq \cup I_n^{'},B\subseteq \cup I_n^{''}$.

Then $\lambda (A)+\lambda (B)\le \sum l(I_n^{'})+\sum l(I_n^{''})\le \sum I_n<\lambda(A+B)+\epsilon$

which holds $\forall \epsilon >0$ .Hence the result

Comment: The intervals are not compact.

Comment: Who said intervals are compact ?Never did I.

Comment: No, but your answer is not related to the task. :-) You proved it for arbitrary $A$ and $B$, I asked for half-open intervals, hence, you can't use that $A$ and $B$ are compact.

Comment: Its clearly written at the top *Let $A,B\subset \Bbb R$ be compact*

Comment: Please read the main post again, I said that the task is divided into several sub-tasks. First, I want to prove it for $A$ and $B$ being half-open intervals.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for? in fact what is your question?.If you don't need the above tell me,I will delete it

Comment: I would like to prove the inequality for half-open intervals $A$ and $B$. I described it above.

Comment: I edited the main post, it was a little bit confusing maybe. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not much to harvest here on the line. For the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$ it is always equality. However, even on $\Bbb{R}^2$ you can simply get strict inequality, for example, for $A=B=[0,1)^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $A+B=[0,2)^2$ and
$$
\lambda(A+B)=4>1+1=\lambda(A)+\lambda(B).
$$